# Links to within page redefine page

Tags: html

I have links on a ,page that I want to use to jump to portions of that page. I'm using `<h3 id="this-is-my-link-to-within-the-page">` and referencing it via a link like so 
`<a href="#this-is-my-link-to-within-the-page">Link</a>`. In Explorer and Firefox, from what I've tested, clicking on the link takes you to the part of the page as expected, BUT the page is redefined with that part of the page as the beginning of the document. I've never seen this behavior before and I'm not sure why it's happening.

You can see it happening here: http://symphonyninjas.com/interviews/michael-eichelsdoerfer/a

Comment: looks like an issue with your url-rewriting, but I'm not sure, all the code is still there you just can't scroll to it (I'm running chrome 17 on osx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On app.css, find this block:

```
/* line 71, ../sass/app.sass */
#main {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Try to remove attribute overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

look at the bottom part. try creating an anchor name for each section rather than the id="blah" that you use for your sections.

```
<a name="this-section">BLAH!</a>

<a href="#this-section">going to blah!</a>
```